# Maximum execution time of 3 seconds exceeded error in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laragon

This is the error when I try to run `php artisan serve`:

> Symfony Component Error Handler Error Fatal Error
>
> INFO Server running on http://127.0.0.1:8000. Maximum execution time
> of 3 seconds exceeded

The server is running just 3 second. I tried to change `max_execution_time = 36000` in `php.ini` and still not working!

Comment: Have you restarted apache server after changing execution time.